# Is it possible to call static method using object?

Tags: static-methods

this may be a basic question, but please anyone answer.
As we know static members belong to class and we can call them using classname. But in below example we are calling the static method using reference.

```
class One
{
  static void show()
  {
    System.out.println("one");
  }
}

class Two extends One
{
  static void show()
  {
    System.out.println("Two");
  }
}

public class RuntimePoly
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    One o=new Two();
    o.show();
  }
}
```

I am getting correct output.

Answer (score 0):

A static *method* is still a method.

From wikipedia:

> A method in object-oriented programming (OOP) is a procedure associated with a message and an object

It is static in the sense that it doesn't actually use the object it is associated with, but is still "a procedure associated with [...] an object". The static call `A.b()` could also be written `((A) null).b()` (in Java) since the instance is never used and shows a bit more explicitly, where the method resolution comes in.